# How to select div without background-image

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I created a template for my project pages in WP. In the template there is a slider that takes the pictures from advanced image fields. I set the slider to contain 4 slides but some of the projects have only 3 pictures, so the the fourth slide shows up empty in the frontend.

I'm looking for a way to say "If the fourth slide doesn't have a background-image don't display it"

I attached some screenshots to show the difference in the code.

[slide without background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR6i5.png)

[slide with background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJIwz.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and a **specific** question about that code. Is this a CSS problem, an HTML problem, a jQuery problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check if an element doesn't have a **background image** you can read the **css properties** with **javascript** and check if the result is **none** then do what ever you want, here's an example to demonstrate, as you see i have **4 slides** but only **2 of them** will be shown

```js
// Select all your slides
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.et_pb_slider');

slides.forEach(slide => {
    let backgroundImg = getComputedStyle(slide)['background-image'];
    
    // check if there is no image
    if(backgroundImg == 'none'){
        // Add custom style or Do whatever you want
        slide.classList.add('custom-css');
    }
});
```

```css
.et_pb_slider {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.bg-1 {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/229/200/300');
}

.bg-2 {
    /* no image here */
}

.bg-3 {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300');
}

.bg-4 {
    /* no image here */
}

.custom-css {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="et_pb_slider bg-1"></div>
<div class="et_pb_slider bg-2"></div>
<div class="et_pb_slider bg-3"></div>
<div class="et_pb_slider bg-4"></div>
```

Comment: @IlariaBassi use et_pb_slider class because u need to loop over all slides

Comment: @IlariaBassi i have updated my solution

Comment: Thanks! With your code I managed to add the custom class with "display:none" to the last slide, the problem is that when the slider reach the last slide, the whole slideshow disappears... I thought it would restart from the beginning showing the first slide again.

Comment: I tried to use .et_pb_slider, .et_pb_slides and .et_pb_slide (separately) but it adds the custom class to all the slides so the whole slider disappears. The only class that targets exactly the right elements is .et_pb_slide_3_tb_body but as I Explained in the first comment, when the slider reaches the fourth slide it disappears.

Comment: then just add this in your css styles   .et_pb_slide_3_tb_body{display:none;}